# Calculating the constant from a mixed joint distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

Suppose that three random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ have a mixed joint distribution with p.f./p.d.f.:

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \int_0^1\left(c\space x_1^{1+x_2+x_3}(1-x_1)^{3-x_2-x_3} \right)\mathrm{d}x_1$$

if $0 < x_1 < 1$ and $x_2, x_3 \in [0,1].$

Determine the value of constant $c.$

When I simplify the values:

$$c \int_0^1\left(x_1^{1+x_2+x_3}-x_1^{4} \right)\mathrm{d}x_1$$

I notice that $X_1$ has a continuous distribution and $X_2$ and $X_3$ have discrete distributions.

How do I simplify for $x_2$ and $x_3$?

Comment: $f$ doesn't vary with $x_1:$ is this intended?  By "$[0,1]$" do you mean the interval $\{x\mid 0\le x \le 1\}$ (which is what it conventionally means) or the set $\{0,1\}$?  What exactly do you mean by a "p.f./pd.f."?  What is your last integral sign intended to mean (since there is no variable of integration given)?

Comment: @whuber This was taken partially as is from Degroot's solution manual for Probability and statistics 3rd edition; exercise 3.7.2. I believe p.f. means a probability function and p.d.f means probability density function. I am a self-study only student so this chapter has gone a little over my head.

Comment: This will take some creative interpretation.  I suspect $f$ is intended to be the *integrand* in the first integral.  There are at least four distinct interpretations, all of which make sense.